# Prevent getting Visa Sponsorship jobs offers

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

How can I prevent getting Visa Sponsorship jobs advertisement offers in the right bar?

I keep dissmissing such jobs, but I keep receiving it every time on page load.

Comment: They want you! You can't fight about that.

Comment: @TGrif but if I dismiss all of it, shouldn't it stop offering ? is it a feature request?

Comment: Do  you keep getting offered the same *exact* job, different jobs from the same company, or jobs from different companies that just happen to also have Visa Sponsorship?

Comment: @BSMP different jobs sometimes same company

Comment: Seems like a feature request.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the problem with a company offering Visa Sponsorship?

Comment: @martin I don't want jobs from overseas

Comment: Ah, makes sense.

Comment: Presumably though there could be jobs in your country that you might be interested in that would also offer visa sponsorship if a successful applicant needed it.

Comment: @martin you have a point and I'm ok with preventing jobs from not Remote and not in my country, but it's more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support this directly from the UI because it's not an often performed search. You can, however, perform your search and then add `visa:false` to the search text. E.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=visa%3Afalse&l=London%2C+UK&d=20&u=Miles&tl=c%23

This searches for jobs that never set the visa sponsorship flag.

Comment: Actually I refer to jobs ads in the right bar

Comment: Then, no, you cannot prevent these from being displayed. Job ads currently have little customisation. There's a very limited number of jobs in your location so we're trying to show you *something*. Sorry that it's not useful, but feel free to re-phrase your question to indicate that it is related to ads and we'll see if there's some refinement to do here.